# Android Embedded Development

Tags: android, embedded, embedded-linux, android-source

I want to make a project like the picture with a device running embedded android.(rasberrypi, orangepi vs..) I do not know about embedded android. If I install the android operating system after adding a touch screen to the embedded device and then change its roms, can I do something like this?  Can you simply tell me the steps to do something like this?
An application like the picture below will work only(desktop, other applications not working). Is there any application development with Android studio in this process?

[image]